# Alfresco deselect faceted search result filter

Tags: search, filter, alfresco

on alfresco search faceted result page when I select a filter, this filter is well applicated to the result list.

But when i deselect the same filter i want to aboard the selection and find initial stat of result list. 
The deselection is not working. Is this normal?  how can i prevent this?

Comment: This question isn't particular clear. Can you try to explain it better please? In particular, what do you mean by "aboard the selection" and "find initial stat of result list"?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to indicate what version of Alfresco you're using - Community or Enterprise? And which specific version?